# Could not resolve all files for configuration ':jacocoAgent'. > Could not resolve org.jacoco:org.jacoco.agent:0.8.7 SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot, jenkins, jacoco

I'm trying to build my spring boot application and generate jacocoReports in Jenkins with Jacoco plugin externally uploading via Plugin Manager-> Advanced tab.

- Jenkins version- 2.190.3
- Jacoco Jenkins Plugin version 3.0.8. (Initially tried with 3.0.4-3.0.8 same error occurs.)
- Gradle version 7.0.2
- Java 11

Below is related the build.gradle file (Please note that the complete gradle file is provided.)

```
      plugins {
        id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.5.2'
        id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
        id 'java'
        id 'jacoco'
        id "org.sonarqube" version "3.0"
    }

    group = 'test.co.abc'
    sourceCompatibility = '11'

    configurations {
        compileOnly {
            extendsFrom annotationProcessor
        }
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
        
        compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
        developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
        annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
        testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
        testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-core:3.+"
        testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-inline:3.+"
        testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
        testCompileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
        
    }

    test {
        useJUnitPlatform()
    }
//tried changing versions
jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.8.6"
}


    jacocoTestReport {
        dependsOn test
        reports {
            xml.enabled(true)
            csv.enabled(true)
        }

        

    jacocoTestCoverageVerification {
        violationRules {

    // Uncomment the following rules to see if they're failing.
    // The rules are commented out so that the build is green!

            rule {
                element = 'CLASS'
                limit {
                    counter = 'BRANCH'
                    value = 'COVEREDRATIO'
                    minimum = 0.0
                }
            }
        }
    }

    test.finalizedBy jacocoTestReport


    sonarqube {
        properties {
    //Related properties
            property "sonar.java.coveragePlugin", "jacoco"

        }

    }
```

Below is the build shell script configured in jenkins

```
filename="/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/project-name/.gradle/7.0.2/fileHashes/fileHashes.lock"
if [ -f "$filename" ]; then
     rm -i "$filename"
     echo "$filename is removed"
fi
    echo "********************RUNNING TESTS********************"
    r0=$?

    projectKey=`echo "project-name:"$GIT_BRANCH|sed 's/\//:/g'`

    ./gradlew test --info --debug\
      -Dsonar.projectKey=$projectKey\
      -Dorg.gradle.java.home=JAVA_HOME \
      #-Dhttp.proxyHost=*********** 
      #-Dhttp.proxyPort=**** 
    r1=$?
```

I'm getting the below error in the Jenkins log.

```
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
> Task :compileJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :processResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :testClasses UP-TO-DATE
> Task :test
> Task :test FAILED



FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':test'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':jacocoAgent'.
   > Could not resolve org.jacoco:org.jacoco.agent:0.8.7.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Skipped due to earlier error
```

Is there any issue with my build.gradle or the script in jenkins?
There are similar discussions related with this problem for android projects, but couldn't for spring boot. If anyone could share a solution to similar issue or a work-around for this, would be grateful.

Thank you!

Comment: The error message says that it could not resolve `org.jacoco:org.jacoco.agent:0.8.7` due to an earlier error. Hopefully that error was logged. If so, what was it?

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply, Actually the error wasn't logged. And the above issue was fixed after re-installing the jacoco version 3.0.8.